# spring ACL - principal/SID not as user, but another entity

Tags: spring, permissions, spring-security, acl

I am looking into implementing Spring ACL for our project which as very stringent and fine-grained security requirements. I want to know if a certain scenario is possible.

Based on Spring's ACL documentation, any object (ACL_OBJECT_IDENTY) can be permissioned for ACL_SID, and the documentation talks about SID being a 'principal'.. i.e. the currently logged in user.

So, if I have four departments (D1,D2,D3,D4) assigned to two Managers (M1, M2), where M1 can administer D1 & D2 and M2 can administer D3 and D4.. I can easily implement using ACL.

Now, I have a scenario like, where departments have employees, E1, E2.... E8, (assume two each in each department in sequence.. such as D4 has E7 and E8). Employees submit reports R*, and I need to protect 'read' access on those reports to :
1. the Employee itself.
2. The Managers of the department of the employee.
3. other Employees of the department.

and 'admin' access to those reports to:
1. the Employee itself
2. the Managers of the department of the employee.

Even this is possible by original understanding of ACL, where a 'principal' is limited to a user, like E* or M* . such as:

```
E1, E2.. E8
M1, M2..
```

and for each report, we could create ACL_ENTRY's like:

```
R1 read, write to E1  //E1 is author
R1 read, write to M1  //M1 is manager of D1, and E1 belongs to D1
R1 read to E2         //E2 belongs to D1
```

In this scenario I will check if any E* or M* has access to R1.

All is OK, but I feel this can get too complex to manage (the ACL entries), if E's come in and out of D's or if M's are added/removed to manage D's..

So, the question is: Can I use an entity object as a principal, and use that to verify permissions when permissions need to be evaluated. Accordingly, Can I add to ACL_SID the following:

```
D1, D2, D3 and D4    //departmetnIds, not usersIds
```

And then replace ACL_ENTRIES with:

```
R1 read, write to E1 //E1 is author
R1 read to D1        // note D1 here
```

This way, if I'm checking read for any E, I'll check if R1 is permissioned to E's D.
OR if I'm checking if any E has a 'write', then I can check for write specifically to E.

Note: While coming up for an example above, I know there is a gap, to see if any M has 'write' permission.. If we use M's D to resolve permission for R1 instead of M itself, we'll only get 'read'.. and If we add 'write' to the ACL_ENTRIES for D, then all the other E's of the M get 'write' as well (where-as they shouldn't). Assuming, this as a problem with my scenario, please consider the question at a higher level.

Again the question: **Does the principal/SID in ACL_SID always have to be a userId/userName or can it be anything else that can be interpreted differently.**

Thanks in Advance.
M. Rather

Comment: Just looking more into what is intended by a Principal, we find this in java.security.Principal's API:

public interface Principal

This interface represents the abstract notion of a principal, which can be used to represent any entity, such as an individual, a corporation, and a login id. 

So, in theory a 'D' (Department) could be a Principal. ??

Answer (score 1):

No, the sid in ACL_SID could be a ROLE or any other *GrantedAuthority* that your system supports. 
You can, for example, give the user a *GrantedAuhtority* for each department she belongs to. In order to do that you will need to implement your own *UserDetailsService*.
In your implementation the UserDetails.getAuthorities() will return one GrantedAuhtority element for each department/role.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand spring security, the complete Spring Security domain in not related to something else, so the `principal` string of an `PrincipalSid` can be anything.

The only thing I kown where you need to take care, is that the default owner of an ACL Entry is always the current principal form the security context.